# Can anyone reccommend a more readable default font for gVIM on Windows?

Tags: fonts, vi, vim

I find the default font used in gVim on windows to look primitive and unreadable in comparison with other editors. I am keen to stick with vim, as it is my editor of choice in the *nix world, so can anyone recommend a better font?

Comment: This may not be directly related to programming but I would argue the choice of font in an editor is at least indirectly related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This question probably belongs on Super User, but since I had the same reaction...)

It's true, the default font pretty much bites.  I use Consolas, which according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas) is the only standard font on Windows with a slash through the zero.  I believe it was specifically designed for use by developers; not sure where I heard that.

This is in my .gvimrc (guarded by platform of course):

```
:set guifont=Consolas:h9:cANSI
```